# How are apps selected to be pre-installed

Tags: system-installation, official-repositories

How are apps selected to be included, e.g. LibreOffice, (or not, e.g. Dayon!) as pre-installed in Ubuntu?

Is there a committee deciding, or a voting by users, or what?

I would like to propose an app to be included in future releases.

Answer (score 5):

The applications included with a stock install of Ubuntu are selected by the Ubuntu Desktop Team. You can reach the team on Ubuntu Discourse, or you can file a Wishlist bug at launchpad.net. Most changes are discussed on the ubuntu-devel mailing list.

The Desktop Team's intent is that a stock install should provide a positive experience for most general-purpose users. They do not intend to provide specialty software for every possible use.

Some communities maintain their own remixes, including installers with their own choices of pre-installed software. Edubuntu and Ubuntu Studio are classic examples. Those are independent of the Ubuntu Desktop Team.

It seems a bit late to consider changes to the 24.04 LTS cycle. Feature Freeze for 24.04 is on 29 February 2024, less than one week from now. Seems insufficient time to discuss any proposed change and gather feedback. Most proposals happen early in the development cycle (November-December or May-June).

There is a long history of various factions (gamers, business, educations, developers, entertainment) wanting more of "their" applications included. For every complaint that Ubuntu lacks pre-installed XYZ, there is a matching complaint that the Ubuntu installer is already too bloated, takes too long to download, takes up too much disk space, requires too large USB, etc.

Changes to pre-installed software **DO** happen regularly. They happen when the proposal matches the intent of the adopting developers, when the proposal solves more problems than it creates, and when the proposal occurs early enough in the release cycle for (sometimes lengthy) discussion.

Comment: ‘most general-purpose users’ is really the key here, independent of distro, but ‘general-purpose’ depends of course on the target audience for the distro. Essentially everybody will need a web browser, so even though they tend to be ‘heavy’ apps, one is included by default in pretty much every desktop-focused distro in existence. OTOH, a vast majority of users will never need a video editor, so only multimedia focused distros will typically have one installed by default.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and thorough response!